# React - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in.. and can't resolve 'net' in

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, fs, webpack-4

new to webpack configurations. I'm getting this error in my app and it doesn't compile. According to countless suggestions from SO, I've tried the setting (or variations of it) in my package.json:

```
"browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "net": false
         }
```

And in webpack.config:

```
 node: { fs: 'empty', 
         net: 'empty' }
```

It compiles but all it does is it has the file go blank on localhost.

Webpack version: 4.46.0
Node: 16.14.0
Windows 11

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Webpack will let you bundle up modules of **browser-compatible code** into a production bundle for sending to the browser.

The `fs` and `net` modules are not browser-compatible code. They depend on APIs which are provided by Node.js and which are not provided by browsers.

Thus attempts to bundle them error, and if you tell webpage to treat them as empty then the generated bundle won't include them.

Comment: I see, thanks. Do you know why the file I'm serving to the browser goes blank on localhost? It worked fine before this error. It goes blank after I set fs and net to empty and respectively fs and net browsers to false.

Comment: add `node:{fs:'empty'}` in webpack config

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not importing the following from express or even `json` or something else

```
import { response } from 'express'
```

For anyone who is using React (happened to me in react). I have even read with NextJs this works but haven't tested it.

Man I did everything like config-overrides and node modules webpack config file updates and also changed react-scripts version 5 to 4 but nothing worked. But as soon as I removed `response`. It worked.

That one line only made me go into 7 hours of debugging mode.

But always enjoy it :)

Answer (score 0):

It took me while to figure it out and I found out that it may be due to incompatible Node-gyp and Node-sass packages.My app is running fine now.

Again, the errors:

"Module not found: Error Can't resolve "fs" in..."
"Module not found: Error Can't resolve "net" in..."

Try this in the following order :

1. Delete package.lock.json
2. Update/install these packages to make them compatible with each other.

These versions worked for Node 16.14.0:

"node-sass": "^6.0.0"
"node-gyp": "^7.1.0" (in my case - npm install -g node-gyp@7.1.0)
"sass-loader": "^10.0.0"